# How can I import modules from other folders?

Tags: python

I have the following folder structure in my project:

```
program
|-bin
   |-module1
      |-check.py
   |-module2
   |-module3
   |-functions.py
|-main.py
```

I am trying to get the modules located in `bin/functions.py` from `bin/module1/check.py` with this line:

```
from bin.functions import X
```

But for some reason the IDE tells me that it is fine but when I run the check.py it shows me the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bin'

Comment: You might need to create a file `bin/__init__.py`. It can be empty.

Answer (score 0):

first thing you have to add blank `__init__.py` file in all folders.

Second thing you have to add path of program folder in `sys.path`

use below lines before import:

```
import os
import sys
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../../")
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(path))'
```

Comment: Thanks! But the first step doesn't really do anything because if I don't create the files it works anyway